# Hashing a password in .net

Tags: .net, windows, security, cryptography

I'd like to store passwords in a database. How secure is the following code:

```
    static string ComputeHash(string password, string salt, int iteration)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt), iteration);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash.GetBytes(16));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implements PBKDF2. Side channel analysis are unlikely on PBKDF2, so basically you are asking how secure PBKDF2 is. It is a known secure algorithm also accepted by NIST that requires a random salt, a high iteration count and well defined encoding of the password.

Now we don't know your parameters, but `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt)` doesn't bode well, as the salt should contain enough randomness. It's a bit unlikely that that comes from a `String`, although a newly generated GUID could do the trick. Finally: we don't know the iteration count; UTF-8 is fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GUID for salt.

Comment: I cannot give a more objective answer than above. I would consider it pretty secure if the iteration count is indeed high enough - but that's just an opinion. PBKDF2 certainly is an accepted method. scrypt (which uses PBKDF2 underneath) could be considered more secure as it also relies on memory requirements - but that is a drawback as well.